# How can I bind 2 functions to one click event to a button(ID="Display") asynchronously?

Tags: jquery

How can I bind 2 functions to one click event to a button(ID="Display") in such a way that Function B() must wait until Function A() finishes and then executes using Jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are not making any ansynchronous call in `A`, the below code will execute B after A has completely executed.

```
function A(){
   ....
}

function B(){
   ....
}

$("#Display").click(A).click(B);
```

Answer (score 3):

Call them in one function. And call that function in the Button event.

Like this:

> > callAB(){
> >
> > functionA();
> >
> > functionB();
> >
> > }

Now call function callAB() in Button event.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call function A from the event. And then at the end of function A, you can call function B.

I believe this would address your requirement. One example:

```
function A()
{
  ... do stuff...
  function B();
}
```

Would this work?

Comment: I don't have access to A()'s code because I am loading an iframe with .src which includes A().

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are doing an AJAX call or something that would allow execution of code after the AJAX call is executed and before the transfer is comlete? If that's the case, usually plugins like this have methods such as onSuccess which you would then call your function. Otherwise, what would the first function possibly doing that it would exit and continue? It's scripting, so it should execute in order. Even with the above examples, if it's an AJAX call, it would continue, even if it's not finished with the transfer.

```
$.AJAX({
    onSuccess(function(){
        doYourStuff();
    })
})
```

Comment: My function A() does the calculations and function B() prints an invoice.